# Unable to append an already-existing h1 to another div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to append an `h1` element (that is already in the HTML) to a div, once you click on a button. It should be pretty easy but for the life of me I can't figure out why this isn't working.

```js
$('button').on('click', function() {
  $('div').append($('h1'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button"></button>
<h1>lorem ipsum</h1>
<div></div>
```

I know I can just directly add a new `h1` to the DOM, but I'm trying to append the one already there in the HTML because it's very dynamic in the actual project.

Any ideas why it's not working?

Comment: Also when I try to show it in an alert....  alert( $('h1') ); .... it shows [object Object]

Comment: what do mean by not working did you check what is happening?

Comment: Does the selector `$('button')` returns 1 or more results?

Comment: try with this `$('div').append( $('<h1>test</h1>'));`

Comment: Your code is working, there is just no visible difference in the states. Also `alert($('h1'))` will show `[object Object]` as you're alerting an object... If you'r trying to debug I'd suggest using `console.log()` instead

Comment: it's so weird, the snippet works but my file doesn't even though it's the literally the same thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should try cloning it

```
$('div').append( $('h1:first').clone() );
```

Comment: no problem :) i put :first there because maybe the h1 you want to copy is always the first but consider adding an id  and using $('#id').clone().removeProp('id')

Answer (score 0):

```js
  $('button').on('click', function(){
    
    //get h1 content with parent container
    var htmlCont = $('h1').wrap('<p/>').parent().html();
    $('h1').parent().remove();
    
    /*
    //get h1 content and append it
    var htmlCont = $('h1').html();
    $('h1').remove();
    */
    
    $('div').append(htmlCont);
    
  });
```

```html
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <button type="button">tes</button>
   <h1>lorem ipsum</h1>
   <div></div>
```